# pdo free result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

there is a mysql function in php called [mysql_free_result()](http://php.net/mysql_free_result);
I couln't find any similar function for PDO.

is there a pdo function to free the result of a database fetch or does the result set automatically get requested and freed when I call `$stmt->fetch()` data?

could someone explain me this difference between native mysql and pdo?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

closest method is close cursor for PDO statements.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php

```php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT foo FROM bar');
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

Comment: so it's not necessary for pdo to flush large result sets?

Comment: for some drivers it is necessary to close all result set before you can create another.

Comment: Not *just* some drivers -- some *settings* provided by drivers require closing the result set before firing off another query, like turning off MySQL's [`PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo-mysql.constants).  Thankfully you can call `closeCursor` and it will successfully do nothing when it doesn't need to take action.  Otherwise simply unsetting the variable containing the statement handle will clean up.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the object variable to null. The GC will destroy the PDO Statement instance, I guess.